# bcrypt : data and hash arguments required

Tags: javascript, bcrypt

I am getting a bcrypt error stating that data and hash arguments are required, referencing line #44 in my routes.js file. From what I can tell, I am passing that information: the first parameter to bcrypt.compare is the user entered password, and the second is the hashed password

```
let passwordObject = Password.findOne({
    subjectType: 0,
    status: 1,
  });
  if (!!bcrypt.compare(password, passwordObject.value)) {
    return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password." });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

findOne is not synchronous. You need to put `await`  on findOne. It seems you are a beginner in Nodejs. Learn `promise` and `async-await`.

```
let passwordObject = await Password.findOne({
    subjectType: 0,
    status: 1,
  });
```

Comment: can i use async await with passportjs

Answer (score 0):

adding the await keyword on findOne worked for me

```
let passwordObject = await Password.findOne({
  subjectType: 0,
  status: 1,
});
```